# Why the relation $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla \psi$ holds at points $P \in V'$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, vector-fields, potential-theory

Let there be a continuous charge distribution in space having volume $V'$ and density $\rho$.

Let:

$\displaystyle \mathbf{E}=\int_{V'} \rho\ \dfrac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3} dV'$

$\displaystyle \psi=\int_{V'} \dfrac{\rho}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|} dV'$

The existence of $\mathbf{E}$ and $\psi$ at a point $P \in V'$ can be shown by switching to spherical coordinate system.

However it is not obvious to me why the relation $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla \psi$ holds at points $P \in V'$. Can anybody please show this to me?

Answer (score 1):

We have that (assuming that we can interchange the order of differentiation and integration)
\begin{align}
\nabla \psi(r)
&=\nabla_r\int_{V'} \frac{\varrho(r')}{|r-r'|}\, \mathrm{d}^3r'\\
&=\int_{V'}\varrho(r')\nabla_r\frac{1}{|r-r'|}\, \mathrm{d}^3r'\\
&=-\int_{V'}\varrho(r')\frac{r-r'}{|r-r'|^3}\, \mathrm{d}^3r'\\
\end{align}
Because we have that
\begin{align}
(\nabla f(|r|))_i
&=\partial_i f(|r|)\\
&=f'(|r|) \partial_i |r|\\
&= f'(|r|)\partial_i \sqrt{x_j x_j}\\
&= f'(|r|) \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_jx_j}} \partial_i(x_kx_k)\\
&= f'(|r|) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_jx_j}} x_i\\
&= f'(|r|) \frac{x_i}{|x|}
\end{align}
And if we let $f(x)=x^{-1}$ we have that $f'(x)=-x^{-2}$, as we wanted.

Comment: Why is interchange the order of differentiation and integration applicable at points inside $V'$?

Comment: @Joe why wouldn't it be?

Comment: because of integrand singularity

Comment: @Joe I think the Leibniz rule will allow you to do it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

Comment: Can you please give a reference about the applicability of Leibniz integral rule basic form in the case when the integrand is singular at a point?

Comment: You could show that the integral for $E$ and $\psi$ exists, right? So you proved 1, and I think 3 as well. And the derivative of the function under the integral exists if $r \neq r'$, and that's 1 point only.

Comment: So should we necessarily have to use improper integrals?